# How to get PHP and PDO working in Godaddy shared hosting?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a fatal error showing when I am trying to get MySQL to use a PDO instance in Godaddy shared hosting.

Code I tried to connect my database:

**code 1**

```
   try{
      $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password',
     array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
     $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   }catch(PDOException $e){
      die('Error connecting to database');
   }
```

When I used this code, it is printing 'Error connecting to database'

**code 2**

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'password';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

When I used this code it is printing an error:

> 'Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'dbname"

Godaddy support is saying it is a string error that I have to review from my end and they are asking paid service to resolve it from their end. I found this both code running in my local server (xaamp).

Comment: How considerate of you to try to get free help from us for your very specific problem that is unlikely to help anyone else except you instead of paying GoDaddy support.

Comment: What point you are making herrbischoff  ?? I am not an experienced person in php or hosting. i tried to solve it out from my side from last 1 week. but not get any workable docs related to it. and my codes are sample codes which you can see in all tutorials related to this(PDO). if those codes are producing error. then their is something wrong from godaddy side where my hosting is.

Comment: Exactly my point: your question is not related to PHP or programming but to the GoDaddy infrastructure. You will need to take it up with them.

Comment: I hope it is a permission issues for activating pdo in php. godaddy support is  asking money for it. i looking for a solution to activate in my end. do you now how to activate pdo in php?

Comment: You are changing the various settings (dsn, username, password) to the ones for your godaddy account aren't you?!

Comment: If PDO needs to be activated through the GoDaddy support and they charge money for it, they would be dumb to let it be done by you free of charge ;)

Comment: @herrbischoff: I am not confident this is a Godaddy infrastructure issue. GoDaddy's tech support is certainly correct to reject requests to debug a PHP program. That is almost certainly the basis on which they have said that support for that would be a chargeable service (and the error many programming beginners make is assuming that paying for cheap shared hosting entitles them to unlimited tech support for a program they have written, on the basis it does not connect to a database `:-)`).

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599753/unable-to-connect-godaddy-mysql-database) may be relevant, and [this article](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/connecting-to-mysql-using-php-216). My guess is that the MySQL instance is on another server, so `localhost` won't work.

Comment: @halfer: You're probably right. But not doing even the most basic of research (hostname of MySQL server from your shared hosting documentation) and complaining about it should always result in paying for your laziness. You can either read and learn or pay others to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure everything is correct in your config array, then add '\' this before PDO instance:

```html
// Define Config Options
$config = [
 'username' => 'YourUsername',
 'password' => 'YourPassword',
 'database' => 'YourDatabase' 
];

// Make a function to easily access it
function connect($config)
{
 try{
  $conn = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' .$config['database'], $config['username'], $config['password']);

  $conn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  return $conn;
 } 
 catch(Exception $e){
  return false;
 }

}
```

Comment: N_Allanov, no results, these codes are perfectly running in local server.

Comment: @Sidharth then you have problem with your hosting

Answer (score 1):

In shared hosting you normally find that the mysql server is *not* localhost, you normally find that your provider will place the mysql server on a separate machine.

Login in to you control panel with godaddy and look at the settings, you'll probably have to create a database first.